# Cant get laravel query with relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have model class *Post* with relationship

```
function postanchors(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostAnchors', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

posts_anchors is simple table

id | post_id | anchor_id

Now I want to get posts if they has anchor_id = 51

```
$query = Post::query();
$posts = $query->with('postanchors', function ($query){
           $query->where('anchor_id','=', 51);
})
```

error *mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given*

```
$posts = $query->with('postanchors')->where('anchor_id', 51)->paginate(8);
```

does not working too
 *Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "anchor_id" does not exist LINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from "posts" where "anchor_id"*

It mast be simple request. May be relationship wrong?

Comment: Question : Are you getting anchor_id field if you are not giving the anony function?

Answer (score 1):

try below query:

```
$query = Post::query();
$posts = $query->whereHas('postanchors', function ($query){
       $query->where('anchor_id','=', 51);
})->get();
```